# I have some errors with some HTML and PHP code

Tags: php, html, arrays, tags

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/xxx/public_html/xxxx/index.php on line 20

Code:

```
<?php
$title = "Home";
$page = "index";
$return = TRUE;
require( "./configuration.php" );
include( "./include.php" );
$returned = @( "harper");
if ( ( $returned ) != @( "harper" ) )
{
exit( "Error. Contact Us." );
}
$rows = ( "SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE `clientid` = '".$_SESSION['clientid']."' LIMIT  1" );
$result1 = ( "SELECT `serverid`, `ipid`, `name`, `game`, `status`, `online`, `slots`,  `type`, `port` FROM `server` WHERE `clientid` = '".$_SESSION['clientid']."' ORDER BY  `serverid`" );
$servers = array( );
while ( $rows1 = ( $result1 ) )
{
if ( !empty( $rows1['ipid'] ) )
{
    $rows2 = ( "SELECT `ip` FROM `ip` WHERE `ipid` = '".$rows1['ipid']."' LIMIT 1" );
    $rows1 = ( $rows1, $rows2 );
}
( $servers, $rows1 );
}

1 part
```

Comment: Can you explain why you wrap nearly everything inside brackets? In PHP that is not necessary, so probably you're standing in your own way a little bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP has no support to union two expressions inside brackets:

```
$rows1 = ( $rows1, $rows2 )
```

You need to add something like a function call, the array keyword or similar.

Comment: Help me  realy,i dont know what is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to create an array the wrong way:

```
$rows1 = ( $rows1, $rows2 );
```

It should be

```
$rows1 = new Array( $rows1, $rows2 );
```

or

```
$rows1 = $rows1.$rows2;
```

Same goes for your last row in your code:

```
new Array( $servers, $rows1 );
```

What do you want to do with it anyways? It doesn't redirect to anything, so it is just lost. You should save it in a variable

If you want to store `$rows1` in `$servers`, do this:

```
$servers[] = $rows1;
```

Comment: Hy,thanks for a quicly reponse,i gonna post the all code,and maybe we cant find and solve the problem

Comment: with my response you should be able to fix it

Comment: A [PHP array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is a primitive type, not an object. Hence, it's `$rows1 = array( ... )` rather than `new Array()`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `.` for concatenation use like this edit

```
$rows1 = $rows1.$rows2;
```

or use `array` for storing them in array like this

```
$rows1 = array($rows1,$rows2);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want to do the code $rows1 = ( $rows1, $rows2 ); ?

Your code looks like a function call, it's not php statement.

Eg: $rows1 = array( $rows1, $rows2 );

Comment: 2 part  -->   $smarty->display( "header.tpl" );
$smarty->assign( "client", array(
"first_name" => $rows['firstname'],
"last_name" => $rows['lastname'],
"email" => $rows['email'],
"servers" => ( "SELECT `serverid` FROM `server` WHERE `clientid` =   '".$_SESSION['clientid']."'" )
) );
$smarty->assign( "servers", $servers );
$smarty->display( "index.tpl" );
if ( BRANDING )
{
echo "<br /><div align='center'> By <a href='http://www.mysite.com' style='font- weight:bold;' target='_blank'>Freedom</a></div>";
}
$smarty->display( "footer.tpl" );
?>